# Android Kotlin ошибка в кодогенерации при компиляции

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

При компиляции кидает ошибки

```
D:\Project\Peshkariki-New\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\app\peshkariki\data\remote\base\BaseRemoteDataSource.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<? super kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.base.BaseResponse>, ? extends java.lang.Object> networkCall, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                                                                                                     ^
  symbol:   class BaseResponse
  location: package com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.baseD:\Project\Peshkariki-New\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\app\peshkariki\data\remote\base\BaseRemoteDataSource.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.RequestModel<? extends com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.base.BaseResponse>> p1) {
                                                                         ^
  symbol:   class RequestModel
  location: package com.app.peshkariki.data.remoteD:\Project\Peshkariki-New\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\app\peshkariki\data\remote\base\BaseRemoteDataSource.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.RequestModel<? extends com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.base.BaseResponse>> p1) {
                                                                                                                                    ^
  symbol:   class BaseResponse
  location: package com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.baseD:\Project\Peshkariki-New\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\app\peshkariki\data\remote\RemoteDataSource.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.RequestModel<? extends com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.base.BaseResponse>> p0) {
                                                                         ^
  symbol:   class RequestModel
  location: package com.app.peshkariki.data.remoteD:\Project\Peshkariki-New\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\app\peshkariki\data\remote\RemoteDataSource.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.RequestModel<? extends com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.base.BaseResponse>> p0) {
                                                                                                                                    ^
  symbol:   class BaseResponse
  location: package com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.baseD:\Project\Peshkariki-New\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\app\peshkariki\data\remote\RemoteDataSource.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.RequestModel<? extends com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.base.BaseResponse>> p2) {
                                                                         ^
  symbol:   class RequestModel
  location: package com.app.peshkariki.data.remoteD:\Project\Peshkariki-New\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\app\peshkariki\data\remote\RemoteDataSource.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.RequestModel<? extends com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.base.BaseResponse>> p2) {
                                                                                                                                    ^
  symbol:   class BaseResponse
  location: package com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.base
```

Вот этот сгенерированный код:

```
@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
    protected final java.lang.Object getNetworkCall(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<? super kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.base.BaseResponse>, ? extends java.lang.Object> networkCall, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.RequestModel<? extends com.app.peshkariki.data.remote.base.BaseResponse>> p1) {
        return null;
    }
```

Как вызывается

```
suspend fun getUserAndSettings() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        getNetworkCall { api.getUserAndSettings(tokenHeader) }
    }
```

APIService

```
@POST("user/get")
    suspend fun getUserAndSettings(
        @Header("Authorization") token: String
    ): UserAndSettingsResponse
```

getNetworkCall

```
protected suspend fun getNetworkCall(networkCall: suspend () -> BaseResponse) =
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            val result: RequestModel<BaseResponse>
            if(context.isConnectedToInternet()) {
                try {
                    val response = networkCall.invoke()
                    Log.d("${getTitleDataSource()} Response", response.toString())
                    if (response.success)
                        RequestModel.Success(response)
                    else
                        RequestModel.Error(data = response, message = response.message)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.d("${getTitleDataSource()} Error", e.printStackTrace().toString())
                    RequestModel.FatalError(data = null, exception = e)
                }
            }
            else{
                Log.d("${getTitleDataSource()} Error", "Internet not available")
                RequestModel.ErrorInternet()
            }
    }
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: какой версии ретрофит? suspend fun он поддерживает только с 2.6.0

Comment: @IR42 2.6.4 у меня

Comment: У вас же ошибки сыпятся при компиляции Java исходников. Больше похоже на банальный classPath issue.